# Make Python Sublists from a list using a Separator

Tags: python, split, sublist

I have for example the following list:

```
['|', u'MOM', u'DAD', '|', u'GRAND', '|', u'MOM', u'MAX', u'JULES', '|']
```

and want it to be split by the "|" so the result would look like:

```
[[u'MOM', u'DAD'],[ u'GRAND'], [u'MOM', u'MAX', u'JULES']]
```

How can I do this? I only find examples of sublists on the net which need a length of the elements

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
>>> [list(x[1]) for x in itertools.groupby(['|', u'MOM', u'DAD', '|', u'GRAND', '|', u'MOM', u'MAX', u'JULES', '|'], lambda x: x=='|') if not x[0]]
[[u'MOM', u'DAD'], [u'GRAND'], [u'MOM', u'MAX', u'JULES']]
```

Comment: This solution for me is full of magic but works perfect! Thank you

Comment: Read the [groupby documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for a start. :-)

Comment: The full line is, for clarity: `[list(x[1]) for x in itertools.groupby(myList, lambda x: x=='|') if not x[0]]`

Comment: @ninjagecko: That's why I split out the `list` and the `lambda` in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164313/make-python-sublists-from-a-list-using-a-seperator/6164385#6164385).

Answer (score 10):

[`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) does this very nicely...

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = ['|', u'MOM', u'DAD', '|', u'GRAND', '|', u'MOM', u'MAX', u'JULES', '|']
>>> key = lambda sep: sep == '|'
>>> [list(group) for is_key, group in itertools.groupby(l, key) if not is_key]
[[u'MOM', u'DAD'], [u'GRAND'], [u'MOM', u'MAX', u'JULES']]
```

Comment: This is more readable than the accepted answer. To the top you go!

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using plain old for-loop (was beaten to it for the groupby solution, which BTW is better!)

```
seq = ['|', u'MOM', u'DAD', '|', u'GRAND', '|', u'MOM', u'MAX', u'JULES', '|']

S=[]
tmp=[]

for i in seq:
    if i == '|':
        S.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
    else:
        tmp.append(i)

# Remove empty lists
while True:
    try:
        S.remove([])
    except ValueError:
        break

print S
```

Gives

```
[[u'MOM', u'DAD'], [u'GRAND'], [u'MOM', u'MAX', u'JULES']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> reduce(
        lambda acc,x: acc+[[]] if x=='|' else acc[:-1]+[acc[-1]+[x]], 
        myList,
        [[]]
    )
[[], ['MOM', 'DAD'], ['GRAND'], ['MOM', 'MAX', 'JULES'], []]
```

Of course you'd want to use `itertools.groupby`, though you may wish to note that my approach "correctly" puts empty lists on the ends. =)

Comment: When you say "correctly", how does that match with the desired output from the question or the linked article?

Comment: @Johnsyweb I am well aware. Nevertheless the semantics of the specification however are inelegant and should be equivalent to `[].split(token)`; the input should just leave off the `'|'` on the ends.