# Split a list into a list of lists by condition

Tags: python

Could somebody help me to split a list into a list of lists by element ('#')?

Input:

```
['1', '2','#','3','4','#','5']
```

Output:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3','4'], ['5']]
```

Comment: Post your attempts please.

Comment: Sorry. They were so bad.

Answer (score 2):

```
input = ['1', '2','#','3','4','#','5']
s = ''.join(input).split('#')
r = []
for i in s:
    r.append(list(i))
output = r
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: @AlexChar This is basically the same as zoosuck's answer above. First combine all the character in the list into a string, then split it using '#' as seperator. Now the list is ['12', '34', '5']. Then split all the strings back to list.

Answer (score 2):

Use string join and split method:

```
alist=  ['1', '2','#','3','4','#','5']
as_string = ' '.join(alist).split('#')
as_string_list = [i.strip().split(' ') for i in as_string]
print as_string_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer:

```
[list(x[1]) for x in itertools.groupby(myList, lambda x: x=='#') if not x[0]]
```

This question is a duplicate of [Make Python Sublists from a list using a Separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164313/make-python-sublists-from-a-list-using-a-separator). That is were the modified answer comes from.