# P3.5: Creating Sublist

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have this code:

```
    all_jobids = ['270', '271', '274', '278', '|_279', '|_280', '|_281', '288', '289', '|_290', '|_291', '298',
                  '299', '|_300', '|_301', '|_302', '|_303', '308']

    intjobs = []
    for entry in all_jobids:
        sub_id = 0
        try:
            current_id = int(entry)
            intjobs.append(current_id)
        # except ValueError:
        #     sub_id = int(entry[2:])
        #     last_id = intjobs[-1]
        #     intjobs[-1] = [last_id].append(sub_id)
        except ValueError:
            sub_id = int(entry[2:])

            if intjobs[-1] is list:
                intjobs[-1].append(sub_id)
            else:
                last_id = intjobs[-1]
                intjobs[-1] = [last_id].append(sub_id)

            # intjobs[last_id] = [last_id].append(int(current_id[2:]))
        print(entry, current_id, sub_id)

        last_id = current_id
    print(intjobs)
```

and have this output:

```
[270, 271, 274, None, 288, None, 298, None, 308]
```

but I want this (dots are just for shorter display):

```
[270, 271, 274, [278, ..., 281], 288, [289, 290, 291], 298, [299, ..., 303], 308]
```

So what I want is a list with optional sublists.
I already looked after other Q&A (e.q.
[Make Python Sublists from a list using a Separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164313/make-python-sublists-from-a-list-using-a-separator)
but it's not the same.

Comment: I think the problem is that `[last_id].append(sub_id)` returns None and not he altered list. Maybe try `intjobs[-1] = [last_id, sub_id]`

Answer (score 0):

A one-line solution (because: python) is:

```py
[[int(id) for id in sublist.split('|')] if '|' in sublist else int(sublist) for sublist in ";".join(all_jobids).replace(';|_', '|').split(';')]
```

**Explanation:**

```py
";".join(all_jobids)
```

Concats all IDs by a semicolon (or `separator1`).

```py
.replace(';|_', '|')
```

Removes the semicolon where sublists are desired and replaces them with a bar (or `separator2`).

```py
.split(';')
```

Splits the string up in IDs and concatenated sub lists.

```py
[[[int(id) for id in sublist.split('|')] if '|' in sublist else int(sublist) for sublist in ... ]
```

Takes the entrys and splits them at the bar (or `separator2`) if there is one. IDs with no bar stay untouched. (Except casting.)

**Output:**

```py
[270, 271, 274, [278, 279, 280, 281], 288, [289, 290, 291], 298, [299, 300, 301, 302, 303], 308]
```

Maybe for further processing it's desired, that the single IDs are lists, too. In that case the simple statement would be:

```py
[[int(id) for id in sublist.split('|')] for sublist in ";".join(all_jobids).replace(';|_', '|').split(';')]
```

**Output:**

```py
[[270], [271], [274], [278, 279, 280, 281], [288], [289, 290, 291], [298], [299, 300, 301, 302, 303], [308]]
```

Comment: Looks good. But result values in the lists need to integers not strings. Desired output: `[270, 271, 274, [278, .. , 281], 288, [289, 290, 291], 298, [299, .. , 303], 308]`.

Comment: You are right. I added the casting. It's still one line, but you may think of do it a little more verbose it production code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
all_jobids = ['270', '271', '274', '278', '|_279', '|_280', '|_281', '288', '289', '|_290', '|_291', '298',
                  '299', '|_300', '|_301', '|_302', '|_303', '308']
intjobs = []
in_sub = False
for entry in all_jobids:
    if entry.startswith('|_'):
        entry = int(entry[2:])
        if not in_sub:
            sub = [intjobs[-1], entry]
            intjobs[-1] = sub
            in_sub = True
        else:
            sub.append(entry)
    else:
        in_sub = False
        intjobs.append(int(entry))
print(intjobs)
```

Output:

```
[270,
 271,
 274,
 [278, 279, 280, 281],
 288,
 [289, 290, 291],
 298,
 [299, 300, 301, 302, 303],
 308]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it works.

This creates a smaller list sublist which gets reset every time a 'normal' item gets added.

```
all_jobids = ['270', '271', '274', '278', '|_279', '|_280', '|_281', '288', '289', '|_290', '|_291', '298',
              '299', '|_300', '|_301', '|_302', '|_303', '308']
intjobs = []
sublist = []
current_id = None
for entry in all_jobids:
    try:
        last_id = current_id
        current_id = int(entry)
        if sublist:
            intjobs.append(sublist)
            last_id = sublist
            sublist = []
        elif last_id:
            intjobs.append(last_id)
        # intjobs.append(current_id)

    except ValueError:
        sub_id = int(entry[2:])
        # sublist.append(sub_id)
        if sublist:
            sublist.append(sub_id)
        else:
            sublist.append(last_id)
            sublist.append(sub_id)

    # print(entry, current_id, sub_id)
if sublist: #if the last item was a sublist item
    intjobs.append(sublist)
else:
    intjobs.append(current_id)

print(intjobs)
```

returns

```
[270, 271, 274, [278, 279, 280, 281], 288, [289, 290, 291], 298, [299, 300, 301, 302, 303], 308]
```

Comment: Desired output: `[270, 271, 274, [278, .. , 281], 288, [289, 290, 291], 298, [299, .. , 303], 308]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `try .. except` to catch `ValueError` exceptions, you can get the desired output like below:

```
int_jobids = []

for i in all_jobids:
    try:
        int_jobids.append(int(i))
        if sub_list:  # We use sub_list for items that start with '|_'
            sub_list.insert(0, int_jobids.pop(-2))
            int_jobids.insert(-1, sub_list[:])
            sub_list = []
    except ValueError:
        sub_list.append(int(i[2:]))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> int_jobids
[270, 271, 274, [278, 279, 280, 281], 288, [289, 290, 291], 298, [299, 300, 301, 302, 303], 308]
```