# Splitting a python list into smaller lists at spaces

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list which consists of alphabets and spaces:

```
s = ['a','b',' ',' ','b','c',' ','d','e','f','g','h',' ','i','j'];
```

I need to split it into smaller individual lists:

```
s=[['a','b'],['b','c'],['d','e','f','g','h'],['i','j']]
```

I am new to python.

The entire code:

```
#To get the longest alphabetical substring from a given string

s = input("Enter any string: ")
alpha_string = []

for i in range(len(s)-1): #if length is 5: 0,1,2,3

if(s[i] <= s[i+1]):
    if i == len(s)-2:
        alpha_string.append(s[i])
        alpha_string.append(s[i+1])
    else:
        alpha_string.append(s[i])

if(s[i] > s[i+1] and s[i-1] <= s[i]):
    alpha_string.append(s[i])
    alpha_string.append(" ")

if(s[i] > s[i+1] and s[i-1] > s[i]):
    alpha_string.append(" ")

print(alpha_string)

#Getting the position of each space in the list
position = []
for j in range(len(alpha_string)):
if alpha_string[j] == " ":
    position.append([j])

print(position)        

#Using the position of each space to create slices into the list
start = 0
final_string = []
for k in range(len(position)):
    final_string.append(alpha_string[start:position[k]])
    temp = position[k]
    start = temp

print(final_string)`
```

Comment: Being new to StackOverflow and/or programming does  not imply you can drop problems without any effort from your side. At least show an attempt, then we can help you with problems in the attempt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Python Sublists from a list using a Separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164313/make-python-sublists-from-a-list-using-a-separator)

Comment: Sorry for not showing the effort-part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a list comprehension as follows

```
print([list(i) for i in ''.join(s).split(' ') if i != ''])
```

> [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]

Comment: This only works for single-character strings though. We don't know if the OP's real data is really all single characters.

Comment: Nor do we know if the OP has put any effort into solving the problem him/herself.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and Aran-Fey, True. Hopefully, he can take this and ask himself what is a list comprehension and down the rabbit hole he goes.

Comment: @JahKnows: my experience is that this will be copy-pasted. I once answered a question with some complex dynamic programming approach. Two days later another question appeared on SO with exactly the answer I gave from a team member that wanted to understand what that algorithm did.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I see.

Answer (score 1):

Here generator will be perfect :

```
s = ['a','b',' ',' ','b','c',' ','d','e','f','g','h',' ','i','j'];

def generator_approach(list_):
    list_s=[]
    for i in list_:
        if i==' ':
            if list_s:
                yield list_s
            list_s=[]
        else:
            list_s.append(i)

    yield list_s

closure=generator_approach(s)
print(list(closure))
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or simply in one line, `result = [list(item) for item in ''.join(s).split()]`

Answer (score 0):

This is one functional way.

```
s = ['a','b',' ',' ','b','c',' ','d','e','f','g','h',' ','i','j']

res = list(map(list, ''.join(s).split()))

# [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby

s = ['a','b',' ',' ','b','c',' ','d','e','f','g','h',' ','i','j']

t = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(s, str.isspace) if not k]

print(t)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]
```

This doesn't require the strings to be single letter like many of the `join()` and `split()` solutions:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> s = ['abc','bcd',' ',' ','bcd','cde',' ','def','efg','fgh','ghi','hij',' ','ijk','jkl']
>>> 
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(s, str.isspace) if not k]
[['abc', 'bcd'], ['bcd', 'cde'], ['def', 'efg', 'fgh', 'ghi', 'hij'], ['ijk', 'jkl']]
>>>
```

I can never pass up an opportunity to (ab)use `groupby()`