# How do I scrape a site (using Python3) if the site's content all exists within one tag?

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping

Struggling with trying to scrape [a very bare bones website](https://results.co.kendall.il.us/) with elections results on it. All of the content is in one `<pre />` tag. Obviously it's very difficult to parse this into json using python 3 the way I normally would.

In a previous year, when I had to scrape this site, I only needed two races' results info so I did something like this:

```
def scrape_kendall():
    COUNTY_NAME = "Kendall"
    # sets URLs
    KENDALL_RACE_URL = 'https://results.co.kendall.il.us/'
    
    #gets data
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(KENDALL_RACE_URL).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    # creates empty list for results info
    kendall_county_results = []

    data = soup.find('pre').text
    precincts_total = 87
    rows = data.splitlines()

    for index, row in enumerate(rows):
        if row.startswith(" PRECINCTS"):
            precincts_reporting = int(row[-2:])

        if row == "COUNTY BOARD MEMBER-DIST.1":
            dist1_race_name = row

            dist1_race_obj = initialize_race_obj(dist1_race_name,precincts_reporting,precincts_total,COUNTY_NAME)

        if index >= 115 and index <= 119: # hard-coded
            cand_index = int(str(index)[-1:]) - 2
            cand_info, full_name, party = get_candidate_info(row)
                
            first_name, middle_name, last_name = parse_name(full_name)

            votes = get_vote_count(cand_info)
            
            formatted_candidate_info = get_candidates_in_race_obj( 
                first_name, middle_name, last_name, 
                votes, party, cand_index)

            dist1_race_obj["reporting_units"][0]['candidates'].append(formatted_candidate_info)

...etc
```

This results in data that looks like this:

````
[
    {
        "name": "County Board Member-Dist.1",
        "description": "",
        "election_date": "2020-11-03",
        "market": "chinews",
        "uncontested": false,
        "amendment": false,
        "state_postal": "IL",
        "recount": false,
        "reporting_units": [
            {
                "name": "Kendall",
                "level": "county",
                "district_type": "",
                "state_postal": "IL",
                "geo_id": "",
                "electoral_vote_total": 0,
                "precincts_reporting": 0,
                "total_precincts": 87,
                "data_source_update_time": "2020-11-20T20:10:15+0000",
                "candidates": [
                    {
                        "first_name": "Scott",
                        "middle_name": "",
                        "last_name": "Gengler",
                        "vote_count": 14696,
                        "party": "REP",
                        "ballot_order": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "first_name": "Brian",
                        "middle_name": "E.",
                        "last_name": "Debolt",
                        "vote_count": 12867,
                        "party": "REP",
                        "ballot_order": 4
                    },```
...etc.
````

`intialize_race_obj`, `get_candidate_info`, `parse_name` and `get_vote_count` are all util functions, some also involve some hard-coding. Because I only needed two races' results info, I made my peace with hard-coding some stuff and using `if` statements (like above). In the future, I may need info for 10 or 20 races and I'm def not up for hard-coding or using `if` statements like this in that scenario. Any ideas on how to scrape this site using python 3 in a more programmatic way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific answer that will always work. In your case, there are clear enters between the different sections. So therefore I would create a manual parser that focuses on getting those different sections.

Some example code I could come up with is shown below, but I'll first mention the steps that I took.

1. Get the data set from the website, and store it in a local file (save some energy).
2. Manually find the point of splitting the summary data (the header on top) and the body with the vote counts.
3. Parse the header line for line manually, this will break if somethings changes, but hey, you probably only have to do it once (cross your fingers).
4. Parse the body, where I partition the body into multiple sections, where every section is contained between two enters. An example section would be

   ```
   AURORA MAYOR
   VOTE FOR  1
       (WITH 3 OF 3 PRECINCTS COUNTED)
    RICHARD C. IRVIN .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .        237   62.20           207            30             0
    JUDD LOFCHIE  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .         59   15.49            56             3             0
    JOHN LAESCH.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .         85   22.31            63            22             0
   ```
5. Then manually parse the section, for which I leave room to parse every candidate.

Now I didn't fully finalized the scraping, but that is part of the fun for you.
But this should set you up with a framework of how to handle an arbitrary large number of sections and candidates.

### Code

```
import itertools
import urllib.request
from argparse import Namespace
from pprint import pprint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_data(url, file='data.txt'):
    """ Retrieve the bare bone data from a weblink and stores it in provided file.  """
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as page:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')
        data = soup.find('pre').text.split('\n')

        with open(file, 'w') as file:
            file.writelines(data)


def clean_data(file='data.txt', header=15, ignore=False):
    """
        Clean the data, where the first n lines are for the header or ignored.

    :param file: (str) Name of the file to load.
    :param header: (int) Number of lines used for header or skipped when ignore is True.
    :param ignore: (bool) If True, skips the lines indicated by header.
    :return:
    """
    with open(file, 'r') as file:
        data = file.readlines()

    header, body = data[:header], data[header:]

    data_header = generate_header(header)
    data_body = generate_body(body, columns=data_header.columns)

    # pprint(vars(data_header))
    pprint(vars(data_body))


def parse_numbers(line: str, columns, missing: list = None, fill_value='-') -> dict:
    values = list(filter(str.strip, line.split('  ')))
    if len(values) == len(columns):
        return dict(zip(columns, values))
    if all(int(value) == 0 for value in values):
        return dict(zip(columns, ['0'] * len(columns)))
    raise ValueError(f"Unknown handling of missing values."
                     f"\nColumns: {columns}Line: \n{line}Values: \n{values}")


def generate_header(header: list[str]):
    """ Manually parse the header (hopefully only once).  """
    clean_data = list(filter(bool, ''.join(header).split('\n')))
    name, description, status = list(filter(str.strip, clean_data[0].split('  ')))
    date = clean_data[1].strip()
    country, state = list(map(str.strip, clean_data[2].split(',')))
    election_date = clean_data[3].strip()
    columns = list(filter(str.strip, clean_data[4].split('  ')))

    summary = {}
    for row in clean_data[5:11]:
        pass

    return Namespace(
            name=name,
            description=description,
            status=status,
            date=date,
            country=country,
            state=state,
            election_date=election_date,
            columns=columns,
            summary=summary
    )


def generate_body(body: list[str], columns=None):
    clean_body = list(map(str.strip, ''.join(body).split('\n')))
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/52943710/10961342
    sections = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(clean_body, key=bool) if key]
    metadata = []

    for section in sections:
        function = section[0]
        vote = [row.startswith('VOTE FOR') for row in section].index(True)  # locate where `VOTE FOR`
        info = ' '.join(map(str.strip, section[1:vote + 2]))
        candidates = []

        for candidate in section[vote + 2:]:
            name = candidate.split('.')[0].strip()
            numbers = candidate.rsplit('.  .')[-1]
            data = parse_numbers(numbers, columns)
            candidates.append({"name": name, "data": data})

        metadata.append({"function": function, "info": info, "candidates": candidates})

    pprint(metadata, sort_dicts=False)
    return Namespace(body=metadata)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Retrieve the original data set.
    # get_data('https://results.co.kendall.il.us/')
    clean_data()
```

#### Output

```
[{'function': 'AURORA MAYOR',
  'info': 'VOTE FOR  1 (WITH 3 OF 3 PRECINCTS COUNTED)',
  'candidates': [{'name': 'RICHARD C',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': '237',
                           ' %': ' 62.20',
                           'ELECTION DAY': ' 207',
                           ' EV, VBM': '30',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'JUDD LOFCHIE',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': ' 59',
                           ' %': ' 15.49',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '56',
                           ' EV, VBM': ' 3',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'JOHN LAESCH',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': ' 85',
                           ' %': ' 22.31',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '63',
                           ' EV, VBM': '22',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}}]},
 {'function': 'AURORA ALDERMAN AT LARGE',
  'info': 'VOTE FOR  1 (WITH 3 OF 3 PRECINCTS COUNTED)',
  'candidates': [{'name': 'RON WOERMAN',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': '117',
                           ' %': ' 34.01',
                           'ELECTION DAY': ' 106',
                           ' EV, VBM': '11',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'BROOKE SHANLEY',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': '168',
                           ' %': ' 48.84',
                           'ELECTION DAY': ' 136',
                           ' EV, VBM': '32',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'RAYMOND HULL',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': ' 59',
                           ' %': ' 17.15',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '52',
                           ' EV, VBM': ' 7',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}}]},
 {'function': 'AURORA ALDERMAN WARD 9',
  'info': 'VOTE FOR  1 (WITH 3 OF 3 PRECINCTS COUNTED)',
  'candidates': [{'name': 'EDWARD J',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': '339',
                           ' %': '100.00',
                           'ELECTION DAY': ' 285',
                           ' EV, VBM': '54',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}}]},
 {'function': 'JOLIET COUNCILMAN AT LARGE',
  'info': 'VOTE FOR  3 (WITH 7 OF 7 PRECINCTS COUNTED)',
  'candidates': [{'name': 'GLENDA WRIGHT-McCULLUM',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': ' 96',
                           ' %': '7.81',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '91',
                           ' EV, VBM': ' 5',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'NICOLE LURRY',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': ' 77',
                           ' %': '6.27',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '70',
                           ' EV, VBM': ' 7',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'JEREMY BRZYCKI',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': ' 90',
                           ' %': '7.32',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '78',
                           ' EV, VBM': '12',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'CESAR GUERRERO',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': '106',
                           ' %': '8.62',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '95',
                           ' EV, VBM': '11',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'ISIAH WILLIAMS JR',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': ' 47',
                           ' %': '3.82',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '45',
                           ' EV, VBM': ' 2',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'HUDSON HOLLISTER',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': ' 84',
                           ' %': '6.83',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '72',
                           ' EV, VBM': '12',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'JAMES LANHAM',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': ' 32',
                           ' %': '2.60',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '29',
                           ' EV, VBM': ' 3',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'ROGER POWELL',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': ' 56',
                           ' %': '4.56',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '55',
                           ' EV, VBM': ' 1',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'WARREN C',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': ' 76',
                           ' %': '6.18',
                           'ELECTION DAY': '66',
                           ' EV, VBM': '10',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'ROBERT WUNDERLICH',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': '166',
                           ' %': ' 13.51',
                           'ELECTION DAY': ' 149',
                           ' EV, VBM': '17',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'JOE CLEMENT',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': '203',
                           ' %': ' 16.52',
                           'ELECTION DAY': ' 190',
                           ' EV, VBM': '13',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'JAN QUILLMAN',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': '196',
                           ' %': ' 15.95',
                           'ELECTION DAY': ' 184',
                           ' EV, VBM': '12',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}}]},
 {'function': 'PLANO MAYOR',
  'info': 'VOTE FOR  1 (WITH 11 OF 11 PRECINCTS COUNTED)',
  'candidates': [{'name': 'ROBERT "BOB" HAUSLER (IND)',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': '388',
                           ' %': ' 48.50',
                           'ELECTION DAY': ' 336',
                           ' EV, VBM': '52',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}},
                 {'name': 'MIKE RENNELS (IND)',
                  'data': {'TOTAL VOTES': '412',
                           ' %': ' 51.50',
                           'ELECTION DAY': ' 352',
                           ' EV, VBM': '60',
                           'PROV, POST': ' 0'}}]},
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying this out today, @Thymen.